# How to use tornado's asynchttpclient alone?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm new to tornado.

What I want is to write some functions to fetch webpages asynchronously. Since no requesthandlers, apps, or servers involved here, I think I can use tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient alone.
But all the sample codes seem to be in a tornado server or requesthandler. When I tried to use it alone, it never works.
For example:

```
def handle(self,response):
    print response
    print response.body


@tornado.web.asynchronous
def fetch(self,url):
    client=tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    client.fetch(url,self.handle)

fetch('http://www.baidu.com')
```

It says "'str' object has no attribute 'application'", but I'm trying to use it alone?

or :

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def fetch_with_coroutine(url):
    client=tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    response=yield http_client.fetch(url)
    print response
    print response.body
    raise gen.Return(response.body)
fetch_with_coroutine('http://www.baidu.com')
```

doesn't work either.

Earlier, I tried pass a callback to AsyncHTTPHandler.fetch, then start the IOLoop, It works and the webpage source code is printed. But I can't figure out what to do with the ioloop.

Answer (score 1):

`@tornado.web.asynchronous` can only be applied to certain methods in `RequestHandler` subclasses; it is not appropriate for this usage.

Your second example is the correct structure, but you need to actually run the IOLoop. The best way to do this in a batch-style program is `IOLoop.current().run_sync(fetch_with_coroutine)`. This starts the IOLoop, runs your callback, then stops the IOLoop. You should run a single function within `run_sync()`, and then use `yield` within that function to call any other coroutines.

For a more complete example, see https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/webspider/webspider.py

Comment: I noticed run_sync at the time I made this post. Do you mean that there's nothing wrong if I start and stop the ioloop each time a request is made, and it still runs asynchronously?

Comment: The normal way to use Tornado is to call `run_sync()` (or `start()`) exactly once. Calling `run_sync()` more than once (except in tests) is unusual, and in most cases it's missing the point of asynchronous programming (by turning asynchronous operations synchronous, you eliminate the concurrency advantages).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I've used in the past...

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, defaults=dict(user_agent="MyUserAgent"))
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()


def handle_response(response):
    if response.error:
        print("Error: %s" % response.error)
    else:
        print(response.body)


async def get_content():
    await http_client.fetch("https://www.integralist.co.uk/", handle_response)


async def main():
    await get_content()
    print("I won't wait for get_content to finish. I'll show immediately.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.run_sync(main)
```

I've also detailed how to use Pipenv with tox.ini and Flake8 with this tornado example so others should be able to get up and running much more quickly https://gist.github.com/fd603239cacbb3d3d317950905b76096